# variable object property name as parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have javascript object like follows:

```
var school = {
    grade1:[
    {
    "teacher":"anna",
    "student":"jacky"
    },
    {..},...
    ]
    grade2:[...]   
}
```

I ran into a problem as I tried to retrieve content using a function

```
function getNames(grade){
    $('#demo').text(school.grade[0].teacher); //returns an error
}
```

I could use `school.grade1[0].teacher` but I want to have a `grade` variable.

As I tried this and it obviously doesn't work:

```
var grade = 'grade1'; //I also tried just grade1 but it is an undefined varaible
getNames(grade);
```

Comment: Where going to need to see a working example. There are lots of things we need to know such as: is jQuery defined and where is `school.grade` defined? What is the error message? etc... But I don't think jQuery is needed in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try like this:**

```
function getNames(grade){
    $('#demo').text(grade.teacher);
}

var grade = school.grade1[0]
or
var grade = school.grade2[0]
getNames(grade);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
school[grade][0].teacher
```